# Showing messagebox when typing words by keylogger

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm trying to do make that whenever you type a certain word on your computer, it gives a messagebox that you typed that word. But I can't figure out how it will always make this check. The keylogger writes to the log.txt, but no messagebox appears. What am I doing wrong?

```
  public static void Main()
{
    var handle = GetConsoleWindow();

    // Hide
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    Application.Run();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);

    string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\log.txt");
    if (text.Contains("TEST"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You typed the word test!");
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe run it on a timer at a certain interval so it keeps checking?

Comment: You need an event that fires whenever a character is typed, inside the event you should put the `MessageBox` code.

Comment: Is log file empty? It's should be first thing to check

Comment: Most likely you should use the excellent "[Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks](https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook)" library.

Comment: Are you actually logging your data in all caps? (- since that is what you are testing for)

Answer (score 0):

Because `Application.Run()` blocks. You probably press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit your application, which then doesn't run the code following `Application.Run()`.

If you want the `if (text.Contains(...))` to run frequently, put it in a timer for example, or simply do the test in `_proc`.